# QML SwipeView or Tumbler gets reloaded upon content change

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to set up a crawler that holds items with signals that may change over time. Unfortunately, I realized, that upon any signal update, the whole SwipeView is reset, which causes the index to jump back to its initial state.

The following example you can run with e.g. qmlscene to see the behavior. Whenever the trigger is fired, then the currentIndex is reset and the view jumps back to 1/first.

Is there any way how I can remain at the index I was at? I tried a little with setting the index back manually, however, then I ended up in a flickering behavior.
The same happens if I put content into a Tumbler.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

SwipeView {
    id: id_swipeView
    width: 100
    height: 100
    property int value: 0
    property var pages: [{"a": "1", "b": "first"}, {"a": "2", "b": "second"}, {"a": id_swipeView.value, "b": "continuous"}]
    Repeater {
        model: id_swipeView.pages
        Item{
            Column{
                Text{
                    text: modelData["a"]
                }

                Text{
                    text: modelData["b"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    Timer{
        repeat: true; running: true; interval: 1000;
        onTriggered: {id_swipeView.value += 1}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a list of objects as a model, it is better to use a ListModel that allows you to handle the values in a simple way, unlike the list that is created if an element is modified.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

SwipeView {
    id: id_swipeView

    width: 100
    height: 100

    ListModel {
        id: list_model

        ListElement {
            a: 1
            b: "first"
        }

        ListElement {
            a: 2
            b: "second"
        }

        ListElement {
            a: 0
            b: "continuous"
        }

    }

    Repeater {
        model: list_model

        Item {
            Column {
                Text {
                    text: model.a
                }

                Text {
                    text: model.b
                }

            }

        }

    }

    Timer {
        repeat: true
        running: true
        interval: 1000
        onTriggered: {
            var value = list_model.get(2).a;
            list_model.setProperty(2, "a", value + 1);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc for your proposal. Looks like a solution indeed. However, this implementation wouldn't allow me to set up a dynamic list based on a custom property of SwipeView. What I really need/ actually want is to have a the model as dynamic interface property of the SwipeView. I edited my post accordingly. Have a look. Do you have any other idea? Many thanks in advance

Comment: @Nico I don't understand you but the cause of the problem is that the list depends on a property so the whole list will be recreated if the property changes. In the case of the ListModel, this does not happen since a property can be changed without changing the entire model, so it will not reload. In short, what you want cannot be implemented with the elements that you want. You seem to have an XY problem